# Keeping NSUserActivity backwards compatible with Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10

Using Xcode 10 (beta 6) I am able to write and run the following code with no trouble:

```
import Intents

func test() {

    let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.activtiy.type")

    activity.title = "Hello World"
    activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
    activity.isEligibleForHandoff = false

    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        activity.isEligibleForPrediction = true
        activity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Say something"
    }

    print(activity)
}
```

As of iOS 12 the `.isEligibleForPredictions` and `.suggestedInvocationPhrase` properties have been added, so Xcode 10 can  keep the code itself backwards compatible using the `if #available` conditional.

However, I want to ensure this code is backwards compatible with earlier versions of Xcode. When run in Xcode 9, I get the following errors:

```
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        // ERROR: Value of type 'NSUserActivity' has no member 'isEligibleForPrediction'
        activity.isEligibleForPrediction = true

        // ERROR: Value of type 'NSUserActivity' has no member 'suggestedInvocationPhrase'
        activity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Say something"
    }
```

This appears to be because the `#available` macro is actually resolved at runtime, therefore all code contained still needs to be compiled successfully.

Is there a way for me to tell the compiler to just ignore these two lines of code when building for iOS 11, or using Xcode 9?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 10 uses Swift 4.2 while Xcode 9 uses Swift 4.1. So you can use that knowledge at compile time:

```swift
func test() {
    let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.activtiy.type")

    activity.title = "Hello World"
    activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
    activity.isEligibleForHandoff = false

    #if swift(>=4.2) // compile-time check
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) { // run-time check
        activity.isEligibleForPrediction = true
        activity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Say something"
        predictionApiAvailable = true
    }
    #endif

    print(activity)
}
```

(This answer assumes that you are using Swift 4.2 on Xcode 10.)

Comment: *"why would you use Xcode 10 if you don't want to use Swift 4.2"* - to use iOS 12, macOS 10.14.

Comment: @rmaddy: ok.. I removed that part from my answer.

Comment: @rmaddy is spot on with why I'm using Xcode 10, but your response seems to be the best solution I can find in Swift. Seems like the best I can do is to re-write the class in Objc, as there are more C-Style macros available.

Comment: @XmasRights: in Objective C you can use __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED which tells you the SDK version. I guess you have to write your code in Objective C if you don't use Swift 4.2.

Comment: @Michael Yep - tried to update the codebase to Swift 4.2, but 300 errors is only slightly more irritating than using Objective-C

Answer (score 1):

The Availability Condition (if #available) you are using as you correctly noted is evaluated at run-time, but the compiler will use this information to provide compile-time safety (It will will warn you if you are calling an API that does not exist min deployment target).

For conditionally compiling code you must use [Conditional Compilation Block](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID539)

```
#if compilation condition
statements
#endif
```

To conditionally build your code based on the Xcode version you can include a Active Compilation Condition in the build settings (a -D swift compile flag) that its name is dynamically created based on the Xcode version. Then use this as compilation condition. Xcode already provides the build setting XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR that resolves to the current Xcode version( e.g. 0900 for Xcode 9). So you can add an an Active Compilation Condition with name XCODE_VERSION_$(XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR) that will resolve to the flag XCODE_VERSION_0900 for Xcode 9.

[image]

Then you can conditionally compile your code using:

```
#if XCODE_VERSION_0900
statements
#endif
```

I have an example project [here](https://github.com/csknns/conditionalCompilationOnXCVersion)